# How to run .exe on remote windows network path from c# .net core running on Linux (docker container)

Tags: c#, .net, linux, windows, exe

I am looking for suggestions how to implement  running .exe exist on remote windows network path from c# .net core running on Linux (docker container). The .net core program runs on aws batch as fargate container and windows network path is on our on-prem windows network share.

I used process and processstartinfo class in .net core, but getting following error:

Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) to get the exe running in a linux container. Maybe start by getting it to run on a linux machine without using containers first.